# Accessing outer class members from within an inner class extending the outer class itself

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes

In the code snippet shown below, an inner class inherits an outer class itself.

```
package test;

class TestInnerClass {

    private String value;

    public TestInnerClass(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    private String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void callShowValue() {
        new InnerClass("Another value").showValue();
    }

    private final class InnerClass extends TestInnerClass {

        public InnerClass(String value) {
            super(value);
        }

        public void showValue() {
            System.out.println(getValue());
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public final class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestInnerClass("Initial value").callShowValue();
    }
}
```

The only statement inside the `main()` method (the last snippet) assigns the value `Initial value` to the private field `value` of the `TestInnerClass` class and then invokes the `callShowValue()` method.

The `callShowValue()` method causes another string - `Another value` to be set the to the private field `value` of the `TestInnerClass` class before invoking the `showValue()` method of `InnerClass` extending `TestInnerClass`.

Accordingly, the following two statements inside the `showValue()` method,

```
System.out.println(getValue());
System.out.println(value);
```

should display,

> Another value
>   Another value

But they display,

> Initial value
>   Initial value

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method `getValue()` and the field `value` are both `private`. As such, they are not accessible to any other classes, including sub-classes, ie. they are not inherited.

In `InnerClass#showValue()`

```
public void showValue() {
    System.out.println(getValue());
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

because of the fact that those are private, `getValue()` and `value` are referring to the outer class' members, which are accessible because you are in the same class, ie. **inner classes can access outer class private members**. The above calls are equivalent to

```
public void showValue() {
    System.out.println(TestInnerClass.this.getValue());
    System.out.println(TestInnerClass.this.value);
}
```

And since you've set `value` as

```
new TestInnerClass("Initial value")
```

you see `"Initial value"` being printed twice. **There is no way to access those `private` members in the sub-class.**

---

The point is: don't make sub classes inner classes.

Answer (score 8):

The key here is to understand how inner classes accesses the members of outer classes. And how is access to those members qualified in case of `private` and `non-private` members. (**Note:** I'll talk about non-`static` inner classes here, as question is about that only).

**Inner classes store reference to enclosing instance:**

An inner class stores a reference to the enclosing instance as a field. The field is named as `this$0`.  The enclosing instance is always bound to the inner class object. When you create an object of inner class from inside the enclosing class, the reference value of `this$0` remains same for all of them, but `this` reference would differ.

You access `this$0` field using `Outer.this` syntax in the inner class. For example, consider this code:

```
class Outer {
    public Outer() { }

    public void createInnerInstance() {
        Inner obj1 = new Inner();
        Inner obj2 = new Inner();
    }

    private class Inner {
        public Inner() {
            System.out.println(Outer.this);
            System.out.println(this);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Outer().createInnerInstance();
}
```

When you execute this code, you will get output like this:

```
Outer@135fbaa4
Outer$Inner@45ee12a7
Outer@135fbaa4
Outer$Inner@330bedb4
```

Notice how 1<sup>st</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> references are same, while 2<sup>nd</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> are different.

---

**Outer class members can be accessed in inner class using `this$0` reference:**

When you access the fields or any other member of outer class from inner class, the access expression is qualified with automatically `this$0`. You explicitly qualify the member access as `this$0` using `OuterClass.this` reference. So, consider field `value` in your outer class was `public`, then in the `showValue()` method in your inner class:

```
public void showValue() {
    System.out.println(TestInnerClass.this.value);
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

the first 2 print statements are equivalent. They would be compiled to the same byte code:

```
 public void showValue();
   Code:
      0: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/
o/PrintStream;
      3: aload_0
      4: getfield      #1                  // Field this$0:LTestInnerClass;
      7: getfield      #4                  // Field TestInnerClass.value:Ljava/lang/Stri
g;
     10: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.printl
:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
     13: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/
o/PrintStream;
     16: aload_0
     17: getfield      #1                  // Field this$0:LTestInnerClass;
     20: getfield      #4                  // Field TestInnerClass.value:Ljava/lang/Stri
g;
     23: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.printl
:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
     26: return
```

---

**You cannot access the outer class members explicitly using `this`:**

If you explicitly try to qualify the field or method access expression with `this` in the inner class, you will get a compiler error:

```
public void showValue() {
    System.out.println(this.value);  // this won't compile
}
```

The above print statement won't compile, because `value` is not a field of the inner class itself. It's an outer class field. `this` refers to the inner class instance, not the outer one.

---

**Story changes when inner class extends outer class:**

When your inner class extends the outer class, then is when things start to go weird. Because in that case, qualifying the field or method access with `this` will be valid for non-private members. For `private` members, that would still not be valid, as `private` members are not inherited.

In case of inherited inner class, directly accessing the outer class members are qualified with `this`. That means, they will be accessed as inner class members. While explicitly qualifying the access with `Outer.this` will refer to the field of enclosing instance - `this$0`.

Considering `value` field is declared as `public`:

```
public void showValue() { 
    System.out.println(value);            // inner class instance field
    System.out.println(this.value);       // inner class instance field
    System.out.println(Outer.this.value); // enclosing instance field
}
```

the first two print statement will print the `value` field of the inner class instance, while the 3rd print statement will print the `value` field of enclosing instance. Confused?

Remember I said, when you create multiple instance of inner class from inside the outer class, they will have same `this$0` reference.

Consider you create an outer class instance:

```
new Outer("rohit").callShowValue();
```

and then in `callShowValue()` method, you create an instance of inner class:

```
new Inner("rj").showValue();
```

Now, the output of the `showValue()` method would be:

```
rj
rj
rohit
```

You would notice that, `this.value` is different from `Outer.this.value`.

**What if you make `value` field `private`:**

Now, when you make the outer class field `private`, then of course you can't access it using `this.value;`. So, the 2nd print statement won't compile.

And direct access of field in that case would be qualified with `this$0` this time. now change the field `value` private, and modify the `showValue()` method as:

```
public void showValue() { 
    System.out.println(value);            // enclosing instance field
    System.out.println(this.value);       // compiler error
    System.out.println(Outer.this.value); // enclosing instance field
}
```

This is where the problem lies. The first print statement qualifies `value` with `this` or `this$0` based on whether the field is `public` or `private`.

---

**Coming to your concrete problem:**

Now in your code, since both `value` field and `getValue()` method is `private`, the `showValue()` method:

```
public void showValue() {
    System.out.println(getValue());
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

is same as:

```
public void showValue() {
    System.out.println(TestInnerClass.this.getValue());
    System.out.println(TestInnerClass.this.value);
}
```

which is accessing the field and method of enclosing instance. And the field is still *Initial Value*. And that is why the output is:

> Initial Value
>   Initial Value

Comment: Damn, dude. On a related note, I'm going to start using my name in my answers as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

In the above case there are 2 different relations between **TestInnerClass and InnerClass**.

But there is a little twist in story..
there are two objects! and the problem is that we are putting **"Another Value"** into different object! and printing the **value** from the old one..

**First Object:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestInnerClass("Initial value").callShowValue();
}
```

Above method in Test Class creates an instance of TestInnerClass with **"Initial value"**

second Object:

```
public void callShowValue() {
    new InnerClass("Another value").showValue();
}
```

Since the **InnerClass** is extending the **TestInnerClass** another new Instance of TestInnerClass is created with **"Another Value"**.
But we are printing the value from old object not the second one.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have explained well why you are getting the results you see (you have two instances of `TestInnerClass` and are accessing the first), however there is actually a way to access the private members of `TestInnerClass` in its subclass - the keyword `super`.

If you replace your `showValue` method with this:

```
public void showValue() {
    System.out.println(super.getValue());
    System.out.println(super.value);
}
```

You will get the output that you expected.

I would also suggest that if you decide to do this you make `InnerClass` a static inner class because it no longer needs a reference to an instance of its outer class.