# Undefined constructor error in a double bracket collection initializer

Tags: java, collections, collection-initializer

In the following code the `getEntriesNotWorking` method reports a compile-time error:

```
public class DoubleBracketInitializerTest {

    class Container {}

    class Entry {
        Container container;
        public Entry(Container container) {
            this.container = container;
        }
    }

    class DetailedContainer extends Container {

        List<Entry> getEntriesNotWorking() {
            return new ArrayList<Entry>() {{
                add(new Entry(this)); // compile-time error mentioned below
            }};
        }

        List<Entry> getEntriesWorking() {
            return Arrays.asList(new Entry(this));
        }

    }

}
```

Error:

> The constructor DoubleBracketInitializerTest.Entry(new
>   ArrayList(){}) is undefined

While the `getEntriesWorking()` method is compiling correctly. The constructor is clearly there since a `DetailedContailer` is a subclass of `Contailer`.

What is the difference between those two methods, that makes the code invalid? How can I make the double bracket initializer work for this class hierarchy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *double-braces initialization*:

```
return new ArrayList<Entry>() {{
            add(new Entry(this)); // compile-time error mentioned below
        }};
```

creates an anonymous inner class, which is a subclass of `ArrayList<Entry>` in this case. So, the `this` reference refers to an instance of the subclass of `ArrayList<Entry>` and not the `DetailedContainer` . To get the `this` reference of `DetailedContainer` class current instance, use `DetailedContainer.this`

```
return new ArrayList<Entry>() {{
            add(new Entry(DetailedContainer.this));  
        }};
```

Of course, if you don't want a fixed sized list, you can directly use:

```
return new ArrayList<Entry>(Arrays.asList(new Entry(this)));
```

instead of *anonymous class*. That is lot easier to understand.

---

**See also:**

- [Accessing outer class members from within an inner class extending the outer class itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19350126/1679863) - for detailed explanation.

Comment: I thought that the double-bracket initialization is some kind of language-defined-new-in-java7 syntactic sugar for a collection initialization - instead it is an anonymous class with an instance initializer...

Comment: @Dariusz With an `instance initializer`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that within `new ArrayList<Entry>() { ... }`, `this` is an `ArrayList<Entry>`. The clue is in the error message, which specifies which constructor signature it's looking for.

If you really want to use this sort of initialization, you want:

```
add(new Entry(DetailedContainer.this));
```

... to refer to the enclosing instance of `DetailedContainer`.

I'd also strongly advise you to avoid inner classes unless you really need them. Life is a lot simpler when you only have top level classes, or nested static classes if you really need them.

I'd also avoid this sort of anonymous `ArrayList` subclass construction - it's a lot more trouble than it's worth, IMO, compared with just creating the array list and adding the item. Or use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), with:

```
return Lists.newArrayList(new Entry(this));
```

Simpler all round!

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```
class DetailedContainer extends Container {

    List<Entry> getEntriesNotWorking() {
        return new ArrayList<Entry>(Arrays.asList(new Entry(this)));
    }

    List<Entry> getEntriesWorking() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Entry(this));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return new ArrayList<Entry>() {{
                add(new Entry(this)); // compile-time error mentioned below
            }};
```

It seems you are creating Anonymous Class implementation, so this keyword inside the annonymous class refers to the object of type ArrayList. 
So, as there is not constructor for Entry class containing ArrayList as a argument available it gives compilation Error.

Answer (score 0):

```
return new ArrayList<Entry>() {{
      add(new Entry(this)); // compile-time error mentioned below
}};
```

Try the following instead:

```
ArrayList<Entry> list = new ArrayList<Entry>();
list.add(new Entry(this));
return list;
```