# enclosingInstance.newMermberClass(args) in java - effective java text

Tags: java

In effective java second edition, the author says,

> It is possible, although rare, to establish the association manually
>   using the expression enclosingInstance.new MemberClass(args). As you
>   would expect, the association takes up space in the nonstatic member class
>   instance and adds time to its construction.

What does `enclosingInstance.new MemberClass(args)` mean? I googled for this and couldn't find anything. Can someone explain to me and shed some light? I have to take a seminar on this topic...

Comment: You can read up [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19350126/1679863) to know in details about  inner class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means "create a new instance of `MemberClass`, using `enclosingInstance` as the reference for the new instance".

An inner class has an implicit reference to its enclosing class - normally if you just call `new MemberClass()` within an instance method, the enclosing class instance is implicitly `this`, but using `enclosingInstance.new MemberClass()` you can explicitly specify a different one. You can also use this approach to create an instance of the inner class from a static method, or indeed from an entirely different class.

A demonstration may help to explain:

```
class Outer {
    private String name;

    Outer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    class Inner {
        void showEnclosingName() {
            System.out.println("Enclosing instance name: " + name);
        }
    }

    void demo() {
        Outer outer = new Outer("Other Outer");
        Inner inner1 = new Inner(); // Implicitly this.new Inner();
        Inner inner2 = outer.new Inner();
        inner1.showEnclosingName(); // Prints Original Outer
        inner2.showEnclosingName(); // Prints Other Outer
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer outer = new Outer("Original Outer");
        outer.demo();
    }
}
```

Comment: So if ClassA is enclosing class and ClassB is member class, I can make object as ObjA.new ClassB()? Or is this wrong?

Comment: @TomThomas: Yes, exactly - see my example.

Comment: Yes saw that after i posted the comment, thanks a lot :)