# Accessing outer inner class from nester inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes, anonymous-class, anonymous-inner-class

I have the following code:

```
public class Bar {}
public class FooBar {}

public class Foo {

    public void method() {
        new Bar() {

            void otherMethod() { }

            void barMethod() {

                new FooBar() {

                    void fooBarMethod() {
                        Bar.this.otherMethod(); // not compiles
                    }   
                };
            }
        };
    }

}
```

So i have an anonymous inner class, which has another anonymous inner class in it. The question: is there any way to access the methods of the outer inner class `Bar` from the inner inner class `FooBar`?

Comment: Is this a purely theoretical question or were you planning on doing this?

Comment: This is a theoretical question. :)

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763543/in-java-how-do-i-access-the-outer-class-when-im-not-in-the-inner-class).

Comment: @MiserableVariable, @Tim B I expanded the example. Sorry, i thought that it is clear that `Bar` and `FooBar` are existing types and can be extended in an anonymous class. I guess it does not matter whether `Bar` is an interface or an abstract class or a class in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call the method directly using simple name:

```
void fooBarMethod() {
    otherMethod(); // compiles
}
```

This will fail, the moment you define another method with the name `otherMethod()` in the `new FooBar()` anonymous class.

`Bar.this` wouldn't really work, because that's an anonymous class there, whose name is given at compile time. It will get a name like `Foo$1`. So, no you can't have something like `Bar.this`.

---

Ok, I've written this source file:

```
class Bar { }

class FooBar { }

public class Demo {

    public static void main() {
        new Demo().method();
    }

    public void method() {
        new Bar() {

            void otherMethod() { System.out.println("Hello"); }

            void barMethod() {

                new FooBar() {

                    void fooBarMethod() {
                        otherMethod(); // not compiles
                    }   
                }.fooBarMethod();
            }
        }.barMethod();
    }
}
```

The class files generated would be:

```
Bar.class
FooBar.class
Demo.class

Demo$1.class    // For `new Bar()` anonymous class
Demo$1$1.class  // For `new FooBar()` anonymous class
```

Now, let's go straight to the byte code of `new FooBar()` anonymous class. The class will be named - `Demo$1$1`. So, running the `javap` command, I get this output:

```
class Demo$1$1 extends FooBar {
  final Demo$1 this$1;

  Demo$1$1(Demo$1);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: putfield      #1                  // Field this$1:LDemo$1;
       5: aload_0
       6: invokespecial #2                  // Method FooBar."<init>":()V
       9: return

  void fooBarMethod();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: getfield      #1                  // Field this$1:LDemo$1;
       4: invokevirtual #3                  // Method Demo$1.otherMethod:()V
       7: return
}
```

The `final` field there is a copy of reference to `new Bar()` instance. So, the `otherMethod()` is invoked on `this$1` reference, which is a reference to the instance of `new Bar()` anonymous inner class. Well, you were trying to do that only, but since that's an anonymous inner class, you cannot access the `this` reference directly. But, that is implicit there.

---

**For more detailed analysis:**

- [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19350126/1679863)

Comment: What reference is the `otherMethod` method being invoked on? Basically, why does it work?

Comment: Simple solution. And what about accessing the `Bar` object itself from `FooBar`, is that possible ("`Bar.this`")?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Still decoding it. Frankly speaking, that's a wierd code.

Comment: @WonderCsabo No you can't do that. That's an anonymous inner class. It  gets it's name at compile time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763543/in-java-how-do-i-access-the-outer-class-when-im-not-in-the-inner-class

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis See updated answer. The method is invoked on the `new Bar()` reference.

Comment: Which some compilers won't let you reference in source code directly.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis We can't use that directly anyways. `Bar.this` is not available. But the reference is implicit.

Comment: That's the point of my original question. Typically anywhere you have `methodCall()`, you can reproduce the invocation by explicitly declaring the reference. You can't do that with nested anonymous classes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes that is true, because `this` really points to `new FooBar()` reference, and we can't use `Bar.this` directly, as it doesn't really exists.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I answered a similar answer with a more detailed explanation, which I've linked.

Answer (score 0):

If you name them then they aren't anonymous inner classes, they are just inner classes. If you don't name them then you can't call them explicitly, although you can call them if there is no name conflict.

Your code is completely invalid though, you are creating a new Bar but never defining a class called Bar.

Forget the line you say "not compiles" on, the first "new Bar()" doesn't compile...

Comment: I thought it is clear that this is just a reduced example and it can be assumed that `Bar` and `FooBar` are existing non final classes.