# Why I can instantiate a static inner class?

Tags: java

If I cannot create an instance of a static class, why I can instantiate a static inner class?

In the code bellow, Counter is a static inner class but it can be instantiated as if it was not:

```
public class Task {

    static class Counter {
        int counter = 0;
        void increment() {counter++;}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Counter counter1 = new Task.Counter();
        Counter counter2 = new Task.Counter();
        counter1.increment();
        counter2.increment();
        counter2.increment();
        counter2.increment();
        System.out.println("counter1: " + counter1.counter);
        System.out.println("counter2: " + counter2.counter);
    }
}
```

If Counter was not a static class, it cound be instantiate using the following sintax:

```
Counter counter1 = new Task().new Counter();
Counter counter2 = new Task().new Counter();
```

But I cannot figure out the difference between these approaches in practical means.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java inner class and static nested class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)

Comment: Thanks but I don´t agree, because the referenced question explains the difference between inner and nested classes. I´m asking why I can instantiate a static inner class as if it was not static. In my humble opinion it is not the same thing. But I respect your point of view.

Comment: It is the same as being about to call `thread.yield()` or `Thread.yield()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the code bellow, Counter is a static inner class but it can be instantiated as if it was not:

An inner class (whether it be `static` or not) can be instantiated, just like a normal class can. Making a class `static` only allows you to access it without creating instance of the enclosing class. Like you did in that code:

```
Counter counter1 = new Task.Counter();
```

Here you are creating an instance of `Counter`. But since `Counter` is a nested class (that is what we call a `static inner` class), we have to access it like that. `Task.Counter` is the fully qualified name of `Counter` class (Add package there). In fact, since your `main` method is in the `Task` class only, you can directly use:

```
Counter counter1 = new Counter();
```

Now, for an `inner class` (non-static), you can't access that class without any instance of the enclosing class. So to create an instance of `Counter`, you first need an instance of `Task`, like this:

```
Task task = new Task();
Counter counter = task.new Counter();
```

You can combine those statements into one like this:

```
Counter counter = new Task().new Counter();
```

In simple words, the difference is that, an `inner class` has a reference to the enclosing instance associated with it, which a `nested class` has no such reference.

Comment: Thanks, good explanation. But inner classes and nested classes are not synonyms?

Comment: @rperson No. `static inner` classes are often called just `nested class`. And `non-static inner` classes are just called `inner class`.

Comment: I see. It is just a question of Terminology. Thanks.

Comment: @rperson You're welcome :) And if you want some more detailed analysis of inner class, you can go through [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19350126/1679863)

Answer (score 0):

A static nested class does not have access to the non-static fields and methods of the class within which it is nested.
A non-static nested class ('inner class') exists within an instance of the nesting class, so it has access to its non-static fields and methods.